# AI follow and avoid collision with obstacle

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, artificial-intelligence, path-finding

I'm making an AI navigation system based on polar coordinates. The purpose is to move an actor to a position, while also moving away from a possible obstacle on its path.

The code works perfectly most of the time but after testing, I discovered this: when the player, obstacle and actor are all perfectly aligned in either the X or Y direction or diagonally, the actor gets stuck in the obstacle. It's mostly noticeable when the player is "hugging" a wall because the actor's movement vector is clipped by the walls, making them aligned.

Click the buttons in the snippet to see what I'm on about.

Is there a way to prevent this?

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let playerX = 100;
let playerY = 200;

let obstacleX = 200;
let obstacleY = 200;

let actorX = 300;
let actorY = 201;


function loop() {
    // Wall clipping
    if (actorX > 490) {
        actorX = 490;
    } else if (actorX < 10) {
        actorX = 10;
    }

    if (actorY > 490) {
        actorY = 490;
    } else if (actorY < 10) {
        actorY = 10;
    }

    // Vector between player and actor
    let vectorPlayerX = playerX - actorX;
    let vectorPlayerY = playerY - actorY;

    // Vector between obstacle and actor
    let vectorObstacleX = obstacleX - actorX;
    let vectorObstacleY = obstacleY - actorY;

    // Where to move, defaults to player's position
    const anglePlayer = Math.atan2(vectorPlayerY, vectorPlayerX);
    let moveAngle = anglePlayer;

    // If near obstacle, adjust course and try to avoid it
    if (Math.sqrt(vectorObstacleX * vectorObstacleX + vectorObstacleY * vectorObstacleY) < 50) {
        const angleObstacle = Math.atan2(vectorObstacleY, vectorObstacleX);
        moveAngle += anglePlayer - angleObstacle;
    }

    // Move the vector to desired location
    actorX += Math.cos(moveAngle);
    actorY += Math.sin(moveAngle);

    //Drawing
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "gray";
    ctx.arc(actorX, actorY, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "orange";
    ctx.arc(obstacleX, obstacleY, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.arc(playerX, playerY, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.fill();

    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

requestAnimationFrame(loop);


function nonAligned() {
    playerX = 100;
    playerY = 200;

    obstacleX = 200;
    obstacleY = 200;

    actorX = 300;
    actorY = 201;
}

function alignedY() {
    playerX = 100;
    playerY = 490;

    obstacleX = 200;
    obstacleY = 490;

    actorX = 300;
    actorY = 490;
}

function alignedBoth() {
    playerX = 200;
    playerY = 200;

    obstacleX = 300;
    obstacleY = 300;

    actorX = 400;
    actorY = 400;
}
```

```css
#options {
    position: fixed;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
<div id="options">
    <button onclick="nonAligned()">Spawn non-aligned</button>
    <button onclick="alignedY()">Spawn Y aligned</button>
    <button onclick="alignedBoth()">Spawn diagonally aligned</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Angles are *nasty*. Always work with vectors if you can.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I used to do that by getting the magnitude between actor and player, then moving it towards player and away from obstacle if close enough. Probably more efficient because it's not using Math.atan2, cos and sin. I ran into problems because the actor's velocity would slow down because of the minus force given by the obstacle.

Comment: If a problem is solvable in polar coordinates it will also be solvable in Cartesian (if not even easier); main advantage of using Cartesian is that you don't have to deal with the coordinate singularity at +- 180 degrees (i.e. vector math is rotationally invariant). Post the original vector-based code you had.

Comment: Hey! I'm just posting this here because it's cool and since you are working on AI navigation, you should know this exists. Unreal Engine has unreal.js. You can use Unreal and it's AI system, as well as all of its other great features, using just javascript: https://github.com/ncsoft/Unreal.js/

Answer (score 0):

If the angle to the player and the obstacle are the same then we continue the course, as the variables cancel each other out.

```
    moveAngle += anglePlayer - angleObstacle;
```

If anglePlayer is 117 and angleObstacle is 117 and your moveAngle is 117 you get

```
   117 + 117 -117 = 117 ...
```

You might want something like this (pseudo code)

```
    moveAngle += anglePlayer + random(90)-45;
```

Or if hitting an obstacle move left or right

```
    moveAngle += anglePlayer - 90;
    if (random(2)==1 moveAngle += 180
```

Comment: I like the diagnosis but am not enthused by the randomness of the solutions. What about rotating moveAngle some amount away from angleObstacle? When they are exactly equal, I admit a coin would have to be flipped, but only a small angular change would be necessary. So, something like (assuming 0-360 angles)

delta = 15;
cross = Math.sin(moveAngle-angleObstacle);
if (cross>0) moveAngle += delta;
if (cross<0) moveAngle -= delta
if (cross==0) {
if (random(2)==1) moveAngle += delta;
else moveAngle -= delta;
}

Answer (score 0):

The issue is indeed that moveAngle is unchanged when it is pointed directly at the obstacle. A small modification checks whether the moveAngle is clockwise or counter-clockwise from the obstacle, and veers further away (note: my code breaks the wall hugging and behaves badly in the "aligned in Y" case for that reason, which is fixable but I don't care to):

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let playerX = 100;
let playerY = 200;

let obstacleX = 200;
let obstacleY = 200;

let actorX = 300;
let actorY = 201;


function loop() {
    // Wall clipping
    if (actorX > 490) {
        actorX = 490;
    } else if (actorX < 10) {
        actorX = 10;
    }

    if (actorY > 490) {
        actorY = 490;
    } else if (actorY < 10) {
        actorY = 10;
    }

    // Vector between player and actor
    let vectorPlayerX = playerX - actorX;
    let vectorPlayerY = playerY - actorY;

    // Vector between obstacle and actor
    let vectorObstacleX = obstacleX - actorX;
    let vectorObstacleY = obstacleY - actorY;

    // Where to move, defaults to player's position
    const anglePlayer = Math.atan2(vectorPlayerY, vectorPlayerX);
    let moveAngle = anglePlayer;

    // If near obstacle, adjust course and try to avoid it
    obs_distance = Math.sqrt(vectorObstacleX * vectorObstacleX + vectorObstacleY * vectorObstacleY);
    if (obs_distance < 100) {
        const angleObstacle = Math.atan2(vectorObstacleY, vectorObstacleX);
        delta = Math.PI/2.0;
        if (obs_distance > 100.0/32.0) { delta = (100.0/32.0)*Math.PI/obs_distance; }
        cross = Math.sin(moveAngle-angleObstacle);
        if (cross>0) { moveAngle += delta; }
        if (cross<0) { moveAngle -= delta; }
        if (cross==0) {
           if (Math.random(2)==1) {
             moveAngle += delta;
           } else {
             moveAngle -= delta;
           }
        }
    }

    // Move the vector to desired location
    actorX += Math.cos(moveAngle);
    actorY += Math.sin(moveAngle);

    //Drawing
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "gray";
    ctx.arc(actorX, actorY, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "orange";
    ctx.arc(obstacleX, obstacleY, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.arc(playerX, playerY, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.fill();

    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

requestAnimationFrame(loop);


function nonAligned() {
    playerX = 100;
    playerY = 200;

    obstacleX = 200;
    obstacleY = 200;

    actorX = 300;
    actorY = 201;
}

function alignedY() {
    playerX = 100;
    playerY = 490;

    obstacleX = 200;
    obstacleY = 490;

    actorX = 300;
    actorY = 490;
}

function alignedBoth() {
    playerX = 200;
    playerY = 200;

    obstacleX = 300;
    obstacleY = 300;

    actorX = 400;
    actorY = 400;
}
```

```css
#options {
    position: fixed;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
<div id="options">
    <button onclick="nonAligned()">Spawn non-aligned</button>
    <button onclick="alignedY()">Spawn Y aligned</button>
    <button onclick="alignedBoth()">Spawn diagonally aligned</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good thinking. I don't think OP even needs to use polar coordinates as it can be done in cartesian using a displacement vector. But that won't, by itself, solve the wall collision issue.

Comment: I don't think the OP is actually using polar coordinates, as they are normally defined, but instead just using angles to parametrize unit vectors, which I think is totally fine. True polar coordinates would be an issue when very near the origin, I agree.